# Using a cell phone as a PC remote control

Tags: bluetooth, mobile-phone

I have a [sony ericsson phone](http://www.gsmarena.com/sony_ericsson_w810-1402.php) that can control any PC using bluetooth, as long as it has permission to do so, of course.

It doesn't require any server software of any kind, it just works out of the box with any PC (or mac) that is bluetooth enabled.

Is there any program I could use that has the same functionality?

I don't want to install anything on the PC, I just want to be able to use the program installed on the phone.

I prefer Java ME/Android/Symbian apps, I don't have an iPhone.

Comment: More info needed, what kind of remote functions do you have with your phone (remote desktop, music player,..)?

Comment: controlling the pointer and music player as a minimum

Comment: @Phil: Sony-Ericsson phones support the Bluetooth "HID" profile, and are able to present themselves as a Bluetooth mouse & keyboard (rather limited with phone's keypad, however).

Answer (score 1):

[PhoneHID](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~sl203/?id=12) is a possibility... however,

> the Java Bluetooth API *[...]* prevents certain PSM's (Protocol Service Multiplexers - like ports) from being used. Specifically, it **only allows ports above 0x1000 to be connected to, preventing the phone from connected to the computer in client mode** (0x12 and 0x13).

[NiiMee](http://www.niime.com/) can make a Symbian phone work as a mouse.

Comment: I tried it, it gave me a server exception when I tried to connect to my PC. and I guess that my phone was the server since the phone initiated the connection

Comment: @Mahmoud: The _client_ initiates the connection. Your PC is the server. Regarding the exception, see the quoted part above.

Comment: I tried browsing the files on the phone to initiate a connection from my PC, and then launched the app, same exception.

Comment: @Mahmoud: that would be because FTP and HID use _separate_ connections.

Comment: then how can I initiate a HID connection? I'm using linux, btw. GNOME is my desktop.